# Business process custom attributes issue

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, business-process

I create business process itemtype with custom attribute(Mapm persistence=jalo).
After the execution of the first action this attribute is filled, but when the second action is running, in the execute method this attribute is null.

Could you please explain why this may happen?

I starts business process like businessProcessService.startProcess(id,name)

Answer (score 0):

Dear Никита Синицин -

Jalo attributes are deprecated and replaced by Dynamic Attributes. Hence would not recommended to use.

Also, Jalo attributes have non-persistent in nature. May be you need to use use persistence type attribute for your need to persist the value in process model.

Hope it helps. Thanks